# Find relevant string within string

Tags: php, regex, string

I want check whether particular string is present within string or not. And i want to get position matching.

For Eg:

```
$actual_string = "red";
$searching_string = "green red yellow";
```

As we know , above searching string "red" matches with actual string, and position matched is 7th(including space).

```
$output = 7;//red matched at 7th position
```

Is is possible to get above requirement? Please help

Comment: @DKasipovic Almost nothing is impossible for PHP(and other language). If there is no strait way , start a long way. For this , I'll go with explode(split strings into array) then search if 3arrays in order have r,e,d. That's TOTALLY POSSIBLE

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years you got me now. I really do not have appropriate response.

Comment: @All , be nicer to this question please.

Comment: The amount of sarcasm in these comments is too dam* high

Comment: Hai to all thanks for your valuable comments. I think there is no way to get solution for this :(. Googled a-lot. Any other ways to do this?

Comment: @ThangapandiyanMD: see if you can get something with [strpos with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609765/using-regex-in-a-string-for-strpos)

Answer (score 2):

Try with [**`strpos`**](https://www.php.net/strpos) like

```
echo strpos($searching_string, $actual_string);
```

But it will consider the string position that starts from `0`.So you need to `+1` for the position to get the correct position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does't worked in my case. Because above returns only full word is matched.In my case,any searching string which matches within actual string. 
Best eg: $actual_string = "red/blue/green";
         $searching_string = "green black";

Comment: @ThangapandiyanMD, then your question is not clear enough. This answer is correct for what you asked. Your comment here only confuses matters.